# get final changed state of a transacion

Tags: go-ethereum, state, transaction-trace, trace

I want to call 'eth_call' and get all changed state after this call. How I can do that?

I want to use it as 'stateDiff' for next 'eth_call'.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute an "eth_call" and get all the state changes due to it using the `stateDiff` option of the `trace_call` method. You can access this method using Alchemy's `trace_call` endpoint:

https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/trace-call

Alternatively, you can also get state changes due to an `eth_call` by using the `prestateTracer` option of the `debug_traceCall` method. You can access this method using Alchemy's `debug_traceCall` endpoint:

https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/debug-tracecall

(Disclosure: I'm with Alchemy)